# How to use the edge routing of LayeredDigraphEmbedding when specifying explicit vertex coordinates?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, visualization

The `"LayeredDigraphEmbedding"` [`GraphLayout`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/GraphLayout.html) uses an edge routing algorithm which produces nice and readable diagrams and curved edges.

```
g = Graph[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 1 -> 4, 4 -> 3, 4 -> 2, 4 -> 5}, 
  EdgeStyle -> Arrowheads[{{Medium, 0.5}}], VertexLabels -> "Name", 
  GraphLayout -> "LayeredDigraphEmbedding"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

How can I access this edge routing algorithm without also letting it position vertices?  It seems that as soon as I fix vertex coordinates, it ceases working:

```
coord = GraphEmbedding[g];

SetProperty[g, VertexCoordinates -> coord]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Why do I need this?**  First I would like to plot an acyclic directed graph like the one above, then I would like to add additional edges (some of which introduce cycles) without disturbing either the layout of the vertices or the layout of the already existing edges.  For example, I might want to add an additional edge `1 -> 3` to the above graph (without overlapping with `1 -> 2 -> 3`), then yet another one from `5 -> 1` which makes it acyclic.  All this time I want to keep the exiting vertex and edge locations untouched.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** A more convenient way than the original post is to generate a seperate graph with only the new edges and combine the `GraphicsGroupBox`es of the two graphs:

```
ClearAll[graphAddF]
graphAddF = RawBoxes[With[{gg2 = Cases[ToBoxes[#2], 
      GraphicsGroupBox[x_] :> x[[1]], {0, Infinity}][[1]]}, 
     Replace[ToBoxes[#], GraphicsGroupBox[{x_, y_}] :> 
       GraphicsGroupBox[{{x, gg2}, y}], {0, Infinity}]]] &;
```

Examples:

```
g = Graph[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 1 -> 4, 4 -> 3, 4 -> 2, 4 -> 5}, 
   EdgeStyle -> Arrowheads[{{Medium, 0.5}}], BaseStyle -> Thick,
   VertexLabels -> "Name", GraphLayout -> "LayeredDigraphEmbedding", 
   ImagePadding -> 10, ImageSize -> 300];

{newedgesa, newedgesb} = {{1 -> 3, 5 -> 1}, {1 -> 3, 5 -> 1, 3 -> 5}};
{curvaturesa, curvaturesb} = {{-0.5, 0}, {-0.5, 0, 0}};

g2 = Graph[newedgesa,  VertexCoordinates -> GraphEmbedding[g][[{1, 3, 5}]], 
   ImageSize -> 200, BaseStyle -> {Thick, Red}, 
   EdgeShapeFunction -> Thread[newedgesa -> (curvedArcF[{{Large, .75}}] /@ curvaturesa)]];
g3 = Graph[newedgesb,  VertexCoordinates -> GraphEmbedding[g][[{1, 3, 5}]], 
  ImageSize -> 200, BaseStyle -> {Thick, Red}, 
  EdgeShapeFunction -> Thread[newedgesb -> (curvedArcF[{{Large, .75}}] /@ curvaturesb)]]; 

Row[{g2, graphAddF[g, g2], g3, graphAddF[g, g3]}]
```

[image]

---

**Original post:**

A work-around until someone posts a more direct answer on the inner workings of  edge routing in various embeddings:

> to keep the existing vertex and *edge locations* untouched

We can construct `EdgeShapeFunction`s extracting the edge primitives from the box expression of a graph:

```
ClearAll[edgeRoutesF, curvedArcF]
edgeRoutesF[g_Graph] := Module[{grgrp = Cases[ToBoxes[g], 
   GraphicsGroupBox[x_] :> (x[[1]] /. {dirs___, sb : StyleBox[_, __] ..} :> 
    {StyleBox[#, ## & @@Flatten[{dirs, #2}]] & @@@ {sb}} /. 
    {DynamicLocation[v1_, ___], mid___, DynamicLocation[v2_, ___]} :> {v1, mid, v2}), 
  {0, Infinity}][[1, 1]], edges}, 
  edges = Cases[grgrp, {v1_String, mid___, v2_String} :> 
    (DirectedEdge @@ (ToExpression /@ StringSplit[{v1, v2}, "$"][[All, -1]])), 
    {0, Infinity}]; 
  Thread[edges -> (Function /@ (grgrp /. {v1_String, mid___, v2_String} :> 
    {#[[1]], mid, #[[2]]}))]]
```

To construct `BezierCurve`s for the newly added edges we can use the built-in (but undocumented) `EdgeShapeFunction` `"CurvedArc"`:

```
curvedArcF[ah_: {{Medium, .5}}][curv_: .5] := Composition[Style[#, Arrowheads[ah]] &, 
  Arrow, GraphElementData[{"CurvedArc", "Curvature" -> curv}]]
```

Examples:

```
g = Graph[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 1 -> 4, 4 -> 3, 4 -> 2, 4 -> 5}, 
   EdgeStyle -> Arrowheads[{{Medium, 0.5}}], VertexLabels -> "Name", 
   GraphLayout -> "LayeredDigraphEmbedding", ImagePadding -> 10, ImageSize -> 300];

newedgesa = DirectedEdge @@@ {{1, 3}, {5, 1}};
curvaturesa = {-.5, -1.5};
edgeshapesa = Join[edgeRoutesF@g, 
   Thread[newedgesa -> (curvedArcF[{{Large, .75}}] /@ curvaturesa)]];

ga = SetProperty[EdgeAdd[g, newedgesa], 
   {EdgeShapeFunction -> edgeshapesa, VertexCoordinates -> GraphEmbedding[g],
    ImageSize -> 400}];

newedgesb = Join[newedgesa, {DirectedEdge[3, 5]}];
curvaturesb = Join[curvaturesa, {0}];
edgeshapesb = Join[edgeRoutesF@g, 
   Thread[newedgesb -> (curvedArcF[{{Large, .75}}] /@ curvaturesb)]];

gb = SetProperty[EdgeAdd[g, newedgesb], 
  {EdgeShapeFunction -> edgeshapesb, VertexCoordinates -> GraphEmbedding[g], 
  ImageSize -> 400}];

Row[{g, ga, gb}]
```

[image]

With `GraphLayout -> "SpringElectricalEmbedding"` and `curvaturesa = {1.5, .5}` we get

```
Row[{g, ga, gb}]
```

[image]